Does an indexed functor $C \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ extend to $\operatorname{Psh}(C) \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$?
This question concerns indexed categories and functors, as well as internal categories and functors.
$\newcommand{\Psh}{{\operatorname{Psh}}}$
$\newcommand{\Id}{{\operatorname{Id}}}$
$\newcommand{\Func}{{\operatorname{Func}}}$
Question in a nutshell
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a category with finite limits, let $C$ be an internal category in $\mathcal{A}$, and let $\mathbb{B}$ be a cocomplete $\mathcal{A}$-indexed category. I suspect that there is an equivalence of categories of indexed functors
$$
\Func_{\mathcal{A}}(C,\mathbb{B}) \simeq \Func^{cc}_{\mathcal{A}}(\Psh(C), \mathbb{B})
$$
analogous to the non-indexed case with $\mathbb{B} = \textbf{Set}$. Does this equivalence appear in the literature?
Preliminaries
I will refer to Johnstone for the definitions of indexed categories (B1.2) and internal categories (B2.3). Note that internal categories in $\mathcal{A}$ can be considered as $\mathcal{A}$-indexed categories in a standard way. We can also talk about indexed categories being (co)complete, and indexed functors being (co)continuous (B1.4).
If $C$ is an internal category in a "base" category $\mathcal{A}$ (with finite limits), an internal presheaf on $C$ consists of a object $F$, an arrow $f_0 : F \rightarrow C_0$, and an arrow $f_1 : C_1 \times_{C_0} F \rightarrow F$ which satisfy some axioms corresponding to functoriality. (In the internal language, it consists of a term $F(x)$ in the context $x \in C_0$ and a function $\ast_{x,y} : Hom(x,y) \times F(y) \rightarrow F(x)$ such that $(g \circ f) \ast a = f \ast (g \ast a)$ and $\Id \ast a = a$.)
We can also define an internal morphism of internal presheaves to be an arrow $\eta : F \rightarrow F'$ such that $f'_0 \circ \eta = f_0$, and which satisfies an axiom corresponding to naturality. This lets us form an (external!) category $\Psh(C)$ of internal presheaves and their morphisms.
If $C$ is an internal category in $\mathcal{A}$, it can be shown that internal presheaves on $C$ are equivalent to indexed functors $C \rightarrow \mathbb{A}$ ($\mathbb{A}$ is the canonical indexing of $\mathcal{A}$ over itself). Therefore, we may as well take $\Psh(C)$ to be the category $\Func_\mathcal{A}(C^{op},\mathbb{A})$.
We can make $\Psh(C)$ into an $\mathcal{A}$-indexed category by using the functor $CF : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \Psh(C)$, which maps $A \in \mathcal{A}$ to $CF(A)$, the constant presheaf taking the value $A$. Then, we just set $\Psh(C)(A) = \Psh(C)/CF(A)$. Once $\Psh(C)$ is viewed as an indexed category, we can form the indexed Yoneda embedding $Y : C \rightarrow \Psh(C)$.
Background
Given an (ordinary) small category $C$ and a functor $F : C \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$, we can extend $F$ to a functor $\widehat{F} : \Psh(C) \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$ by using Kan extensions. Specifically, given $X \in \Psh(C)$, we can form the category $\operatorname{Elt} X$ whose objects are pairs $(c,p)$ with $c \in C, p \in X(c)$. It is equipped with a forgetful functor $\pi_X : \operatorname{Elt} X \rightarrow C$, and we can set $\widehat{F}(X) = \operatorname{colim} (F \circ \pi_X)$. This construction forms part of an equivalence of categories
$$
\Func(C,\textbf{Set}) \simeq \Func^{cc}(\Psh(C), \textbf{Set})
$$
where the other part of the equivalence is the functor $- \circ Y$ ($Y$ is the Yoneda embedding).
In Johnstone's section B2, he develops a lot of machinery for computing (co)limits in (co)complete indexed categories. In particular, if $\mathbb{B}$ is a (co)complete $\mathcal{A}$-indexed category, then for any internal category $C$ in $\mathcal{A}$ and any indexed functor $G : C \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$, we can talk about $\operatorname{colim}_C F$ as an object of $\mathbb{B}(1)$.
This suggests that we should be able to do the same construction as above: if we have an indexed functor $F : C \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$, then given $X \in \Psh(C)$, we can form the internal category $\operatorname{Elt} X$ and get an indexed functor $F \circ \pi_X$. Then we could set $\widehat{F}(X) = \operatorname{colim} (F \circ \pi_X)$, an object in $\mathbb{B}(1)$. Extending this a little, we should get an indexed functor $\widehat{F} : \Psh(C) \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$. In particular, I think that there should be an analogous equivalence of categories
$$
\Func_{\mathcal{A}}(C,\mathbb{B}) \simeq \Func^{cc}_{\mathcal{A}}(\Psh(C), \mathbb{B})
$$
between these categories of indexed functors, where one part of the equivalence is $- \circ Y$ (now, $Y$ is the indexed Yoneda embedding).
Question
Does the above equivalence of categories (between categories of indexed functors) exist in the literature? It seems like a pretty basic continuation of what's been done in Johnstone, but I can't find it anywhere in his book (there doesn't seem to be any mention of internal presheaves). It could just be something that's known but not written down anywhere.

There is definitely discussion of internal presheaves – the whole of section B2.5 is about them!
In particular, the result you seek is Corollary 2.5.8:

[Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a cartesian category with coequalizers of reflexive pairs which are stable under pullback], let $\mathbb{C}$ be an internal category in $\mathcal{S}$ and let $\mathbb{D}$ be a cocomplete $\mathcal{S}$-indexed category.
Then the category $[\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{D}]$ is equivalent to the category of cocontinuous $\mathcal{S}$-indexed functors $[\mathbb{C}^\textrm{op}, \mathbb{S}] \to \mathbb{D}$.

Note the hypothesis.
This is used in the proof of the preceding lemma, which establishes that every presheaf is a colimit of representable presheaves.

Wonderful, thank you! It's a bit embarrassing that it was right there in the book; I guess it was harder to find because Johnstone didn't call them internal presheaves. A rose by any other name smells just as sweet, but is harder to look up!

In the $\textbf{Set}$ case, we can obtain another equivalence where we restrict to lex functors on both sides. Do you happen to know if this appears in Johnstone as well? I read through the remaining results in B2 and couldn't find it. (And Johnstone doesn't seem to talk about lex internal functors, only continuous or cocontinuous.) Of course, it's possible I missed it, that it's written in a way I don't recognize, or it occurs somewhere else in the book.

It should be there in some form. It is a fundamental result for constructing geometric morphisms, after all.
